# Reduce Matrix to Representative Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a slightly intangible question, but I'm looking to find out whether there's a process by which I can extract a representative form for a larger matrix.  So if I have a sparse 10,000x10,000 matrix, I could run it through some process to extract a 25x25 matrix that also appears sparse.  Notably, I'm not looking for lossless dimension reduction - I'm instead trying to visualize the structures of these very high dimensional in a lower-dimensional matrix space without introducing the additional floatingpoints that PCA or SVD would create.

Comment: "without introducing the additional floatingpoints"  Are you hoping to avoid computation or matrix entries?  Can you give more information about how it is that the $10^4\times 10^4$ sparse matrix will have fewer nonzero entries than a dense $25\times 25$ matrix?

Comment: By similarity transformation you could "reduce" a matrix to its Jordan canonical form (which is very sparse).